# Radio button selected shows a text box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've searched a couple of questions on this site but couldn't find a helpfull one, the problem which I have is:

I have 2 radio form boxes, which are called 'Youtube' and 'Picture',I want this: When I click on the radio box of Youtube a text form shows up, I can't fix this and thats why I hope you do guys!
thank you for you time!

my Javascript:

```
        <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){

   if($(this).val()=="youtube")
   if($(this).val()=="pic")
   {
      $("#youtube").show();
   }
   else
   {
       $("#youtube").hide(); 
   }

    });
    </script>
```

My form:

```
 echo '
   <form action="post.php" method="post">
    title: <input name="title" type="text" id="title"><br />';

    //Picture link: <input name="pic" type="text" SIZE="80" id="pic"><br />
    //Youtube link: <input name="youtube" type="text" SIZE="80" id="youtube"><br />';
    echo '
    <input type="radio" name="youtube" value="youtube">Youtube <input style="display: none;" type="text" name="youtube" id="youtube"/> | <input type="radio" name="pic" value="pic">Picture <input style="display: none;" type="text" name="pic" id="pic"/><br />
    Category game: 
     <select name="cat">';
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
echo '
       <option value="'.$row["nameID"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option> // here is the problem
        '; }
      echo '
     </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
   </form>
 ';
```

Comment: What do you mean, 'fix this'? Do you *not* want the text input to show up? Do you want something else to happen?

Comment: I want to show up not to hide

Comment: What do you expect two consecutive `if` statements to do? It's impossible for both of them to be true. I *think* you want to remove the second one, though.

Comment: Doesn't work, still the same

Comment: Well just ended this 1min after the answer http://jsfiddle.net/yrXea/ it could help you

Comment: @EduardoQuintana I've some problems I guess, I uploaded my whole script to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/WtAJn4zY When I click on 'youtube' he doesn't show the text box thank you very much

Comment: Put your code in another script tag and wrap it all inside $(function(){
//here goes your code 
})  you're adding the change event when the DOM is not ready that's why is not working

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/LHBe2/1/

Comment: Yw i'm glad it helped you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need do this..

```
        $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){

    if($(this).val()=="youtube")
    {
       $("#youtube").show();
       $("#pic").hide();
    }
     if($(this).val()=="pic")
    {
       $("#pic").show();
       $("#youtube").hide();
    }

});
```

this will work fine, but you must be carefully >>look at this mate:

```
<input type="radio" name="youtube" value="youtube">Youtube <input style="display: none;" type="text" name="youtube" id="youtube"/>
```

Picture

when you set a radio name, set the name of radio same..like youtube, youtube ...
also, look at a nother name in form, you use a same name for multiple elements, and this wrong mate, give another element defferant name .. to can get it on php side, without any error ...

good luck

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you don't need to do the actual test. Just show the text field next to that input field. 
Here's a sample: 
http://jsfiddle.net/joeSaad/CTFJh/

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').hide();
    $(this).next('label').next('input[type="text"]').show(); });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You nested the if statements. The code would only be used if they are both true.

Your input type='radio' tags are not "closed" they should end with a slash as in:

> input type="radio" name="something" value="something"/>

The text form that you complain about is already in your HTML code as

> input style="display: none;" type="text" name="youtube"
>   id="youtube"/>

and

> input style="display: none;" type="text" name="pic" id="pic"/>

By default it is not displayed hence style="display: none",
when your if statement evaluates as true, the display: none will be removed

Answer (score 0):

Simplify, and un-nest your if statements as follows:

```
if($(this).val()=="youtube")
   $("#youtube").show(); 
} else {
   $("#youtube").hide(); 
}
```

This simply says if the radio button is the YouTube button, then show the youtube input, otherwise hide it.